# How can i create a function in kineticjs

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am very new to kineticjs and javascript. I tried to create a function instead of repeating the same blocks of codes.

I have got 6 buttons and this is what i do for 1:

```
   Create a layer
   Create the button      
   Create the text       
   Add button to the layer       
   Add text to the layer       
   Add layer to the stage       
   Check if button is clicked       
   Check if text is clicked       
   Animate the button       
   Animate the text
```

I dont want to repeat the same process for the other 5 buttons. How can i create a function and put all of them inside?

When i try i get many errors. Is there anything i am missing?

**This is the code i use to create a button:**

```
var layerMenu = new Kinetic.Layer();

var startB = new Kinetic.Rect({                 // start button
    x: -(800),
    //y: stage.height()/4,
    y: 260,
    width: 200,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4
  });

var startT = new Kinetic.Text({             // start text
    x: -(800),
    y: 270,
    text: 'Start the game',
    fontSize: 24,
    fontFamily: 'Calibri',
    width:200 ,
    align: 'center',    
    fill: 'white'
});


layerMenu.add(startB);
layerMenu.add(startT);

stage.add(layerMenu);

startB.on('click', function(evt) {
                console.log("start button clicked");
});

startT.on('click', function(evt) {
    console.log("start text clicked");
  });

var periodM = 400;  

var animM = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
    startB.setX(frame.time/periodM + startB.getAttr('x'));
    startT.setAttr('x', startB.getAttr('x'));


    if (startB.getAttr('x') > (stage.width()/2) -100){
        this.stop();

    }

}, layerMenu);
```

Comment: Can you post the errors you get and the code of your function.

Comment: Agree with dark_duck there's no reason you couldn't wrap this in a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it sorted,

```
            var layerGame = new Kinetic.Layer();

            //// anime menu         
            var layerMenu = new Kinetic.Layer();            
            var groupButton = new Kinetic.Group({
                    x: (stage.width()/2) -100,
                    y: -200,
                    width: 220

                });         
            function CreateButton(x, y, text, name)
            {
                var nButton = new Kinetic.Rect({
                    x: x,
                    y: y,
                    height: 50,
                    width: 200,
                    fill: 'green',
                    stroke: 'black',
                    strokeWidth: 4
                });
                var txtButton = new Kinetic.Text({
                    x: x ,
                    y: y,
                    fontFamily: 'Calibri',
                    fontSize: 24,
                    height: 50,
                    padding:10,
                    width:200 ,
                    text: text,
                    align: 'center',    
                    fill: 'white',
                    name: name
                });
                groupButton.add(nButton);
                groupButton.add(txtButton);
                return nButton;
            }

            var bStart = CreateButton(0, 0, "Start the Game", "StartText");
            var bScore = CreateButton(0, 60, "Scores", "ScoreText");
            var bHelp  = CreateButton(0, 120, "Help", "HelpText");          
            layerMenu.add(groupButton);

            groupButton.get('.StartText').on('click', function(evt) {
                console.log("StartText clicked");
            });
            groupButton.get('.ScoreText').on('click', function(evt) {
                console.log("ScoreText clicked");
            });
            groupButton.get('.HelpText').on('click', function(evt) {
                console.log("HelpText clicked");
            });

            layerMenu.add(groupButton);
            stage.add(layerMenu);
```